# Выпадающее меню самопроизвольно раскрывается - как настроить?

Tags: html, jquery, css, меню

Всем привет! у меня есть меню с выпадающим списком. проблема в том, что при наведении скрытую область в выпадающем списке - меню тоже раскрывается. как сделать так, чтобы меню раскрывалась только при подводе на название списка?

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
  transition: all 800ms ease;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown-menu>.last>a {
  border: none;
}
.activenav {
 color:#ff4573;
 border-bottom:3px solid #ff4573;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="../index.php">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="last">
          <a href="../"></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не использовать скрытие при помощи opacity. Например, сделать нулевую высоту.

Comment: т.е. вместо opacity = 0/1 использовать height = 0/auto ?

Comment: @Вася, у тебя разметка какая-то странная. Не пойму, почему так. Про opacity - нет, если ты его хочешь анимировать. Т. е. сделать анимацию только на opacity, а height менять мгновенно.

Comment: вот - наглядный пример http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/pjej7o2m/
здесь почему-то все ништяк..

Comment: @Вася, ну так там бутстраповские стили и скрипты полключены, а у тебя - нет.

Comment: Стоп.. А где там плавное появление-то??

Comment: ну, не буду же я весь код страницы приводить - правда ж ведь? так, фрагментик. но там именно такое поведения как я хочу, тллько что мне не хватает - не понятно..

Comment: что означает tabindex="-1" - может в этом дело?

Comment: Что на него нельзя переходить при помощи клавиши tab. Не при чём он.

Comment: вместо opacity=0 поставил display:none - и все заработало! вопрос снят

Comment: @Вася, анимации же не работают с display.

Comment: блин, точно - вся анимация пропала - так как же быть?..

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24748/discussion-between--and-qwertiy).

Answer (score -1):

Чтоб раскрывалось при подводе на название вам `:hover` нужно указывать на название. То есть что-то в этом роде:

```
.dropdown a:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```